# Align an image center, bottom of a responsive div

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

```
<div id="banner" class="cf">
        <div class="banner container">
            <hr/>
            <p class="banner-text">
            Some text here
            <span class="sub-bt">That's it.</span>
            </p>
            <a href="#" rel="nofollow" class="learn-btn">Learn More</a>

            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/responsive_ex.png" class="res-ex">
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the code for the issue as far. I need to position the image with a class of "res-ex" to the bottom of the div class of "banner".

I've tried multiple table-cell and position codes but just can't seem to get it to work.

The design is also responsive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use positioning to place the image at the bottom of the div and then use CSS transforms to center it.

```css
.wrap {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background: #f09d09;
}

.wrap img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt=""/>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gj1rmd96/1/)

Comment: How would you have this vertical centered as well?

Comment: The magic is here: `left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%);` could you explain them? particularly the transform.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
.res-ex {
    position:absolute;
    min-width:100px;
    min-height:100px;
    bottom:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
.banner.container {
    position:relative;
}
```

You need set `position:absolute` and `display:inline-block` (or `display:block`) for the image and `position:relative` for its container.
Then you set `bottom:0` for the image.

Comment: I imagine this would have worked, but Paulie_D's method was what I implemented first. Thank you though.

Comment: How is this gonna be centered?

Comment: From the description of the post, I understood that Spencer wanted to position the div at the bottom of the container. If it needs to be centered, then this is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/2ax92smb/